# Moving xlabel to the right (x label style does not work?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, axis

I want to move the xlabel "t" to the right end of the x-axis. I tried x label style, but it does not work for me somehow. What else could I try?

I'd be fine with a separate node or also with a "$t \rightarrow$" somewhere below the graphs of the functions, but unfortunately I failing at doing this.

Any hint or help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
\begin{figure}
    %\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            minor tick num=0,
            axis lines  = middle,
            axis line style = {shorten > =-5mm},
            xlabel       = {$t$},
            %xlabel={$t$ \diagramarrow},
            axis y line=left,
            axis x line=middle,
            width=1.0*\textwidth,
            height=0.55*\textwidth,
            %xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
            xtick={3.14159,2*3.14159,3*3.14159,4*3.14159,5*3.14159,6*3.14159,6.5*3.14159},
            yticklabels=\empty,
            xticklabels={ , $2\pi$, , $4\pi$, , , $\frac{13}{2}\pi$ },
            %every axis/.append style={font=\small},
            ymax=8,
            ymin=-8,
            legend cell align={left},
            legend style={at={($(0.26,1)$)},nodes={scale=1.5, transform shape}},
            %xmin = -1,
            y axis line style={<->}
        ]
            %node[pos=42355, below=2352350, scale=12]{$t\longrightarrow$}
            \addplot[smooth,teal,mark=none, densely dashed, thick,
            domain=0:0.65*31.4159,samples=1000]
                { cos(deg(x))};
                \addlegendentry[scale=0.6]{$\gamma_{0,1}$}
                %node [pos=0.5, below=200, scale=0.8] {$\gamma_{0,1}=\cos t$};
            \addplot[smooth,red,mark=none,  densely dotted, thick,domain=0:0.65*31.4159,samples=1000]
                { ( (3/8)*x*cos(deg(x)) - (9/32)*sin(deg(x)) - (1/32) * sin(3*deg(x))  )};
                \addlegendentry[scale=0.6]{$\gamma_{1,1}$}
                %node [pos=0.5, below=200, scale=0.8] {$\gamma_{0,1}=\cos t$};
            \addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none,thick,  domain=0:0.65*31.4159,samples=1000]
                { cos(deg(x)) + 0.5*((3/8)*x*cos(deg(x))-(9/32)*sin(deg(x))-(1/32)*sin(3*deg(x))  )};
                \addlegendentry[scale=0.6]{$\gamma_{0,1}+\varepsilon\gamma_{1,1}$}
                %node [pos=0.5, below=200, scale=0.8] {$\gamma_{0,1}=\cos t$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `xlabel style={ xshift=1.5em}, ` and remove `axis x line=middle,`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I also found `every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west}` to be working.

Comment: To help other readers put compilable code as an answer, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`  (with only the necessary packages) and its output. Then you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Ay news? Do you check received answers? Is no one worth to  be awarded by upvoting it?  Some of them addresses some other issues of your code fragment ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which we can test/compile as it is.
- Since you not provide it, the preamble content, which is related to diagram, is unknown.
- You need to cleanup `axis` settings (for example, axis are defined several times).
- The `xlabel style` works as expected, see MWE below.
- It seems that culprit of your troubles is unusual definition of the `x axis line style`. What you like to achieve with it you can get by use of the `enlarge x limits`.
- See, if the following MWE produces what you after:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height=0.55*\textwidth,
    width=\textwidth,
%
    axis lines = center,
    y axis line style={stealth-stealth},
    enlarge x limits = {0.1, upper},
    xlabel = {$t$},
    xlabel style = {anchor=west},
%
    trig format= rad,
    xtick = {pi,2*pi,3*pi,4*pi,5*pi,6*pi},
    xticklabels = {$\pi$, $2\pi$, $3\pi$, $4\pi$, $5\pi$, $6\pi$,$6.5\pi$},
    ytick = \empty,
    ticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
%
    domain= 0:6*pi, samples=301,
    no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
%
    legend pos = north west,
    legend cell align={left},
    legend style={font=\scriptsize},
            ]
\addplot[teal, densely dashed]  {cos(x)};
\addplot[red,  densely dotted]  {(3/8)*x*cos(x) - (9/32)*sin(x) - (1/32)*sin(3*x)};
\addplot[blue]  {cos(x) + 0.5*(3/8)*x*cos(x) - (9/32)*sin(x)-(1/32)*sin(3*x)};
%
\legend{$\gamma_{0,1}$, $\gamma_{1,1}$, $\gamma_{0,1}+\varepsilon\gamma_{1,1}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            minor tick num=0,
            axis lines  = middle,
            axis line style = {shorten > =-5mm},
            axis y line=left,
            axis x line=middle,
            width=1.0*\textwidth,
            height=0.55*\textwidth,
            %xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
            xtick={3.14159,2*3.14159,3*3.14159,4*3.14159,5*3.14159,6*3.14159,6.5*3.14159},
            yticklabels=\empty,
            xticklabels={ , $2\pi$, , $4\pi$, , , $\frac{13}{2}\pi$ },
            every axis/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
            ymax=8,
            ymin=-8,
            legend cell align={left},
            legend style={at={($(0.21,1)$)},nodes={scale=1.2, transform shape}},
            y axis line style={<->},
            every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
            xlabel       = {$t$}
            %xlabel style={ xshift=2em}
        ]
            %node[pos=42355, below=2352350, scale=12]{$t\longrightarrow$}
            \addplot[smooth,teal,mark=none, densely dashed, thick,
            domain=0:0.65*31.4159,samples=1000]
                { cos(deg(x))};
                \addlegendentry[scale=0.6]{$\gamma_{0,1}$}
                %node [pos=0.5, below=200, scale=0.8] {$\gamma_{0,1}=\cos t$};
            \addplot[smooth,red,mark=none,  densely dotted, thick,domain=0:0.65*31.4159,samples=1000]
                { ( (3/8)*x*cos(deg(x)) - (9/32)*sin(deg(x)) - (1/32) * sin(3*deg(x))  )};
                \addlegendentry[scale=0.6]{$\gamma_{1,1}$}
                %node [pos=0.5, below=200, scale=0.8] {$\gamma_{0,1}=\cos t$};
            \addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none,thick,  domain=0:0.65*31.4159,samples=1000]
                { cos(deg(x)) + 0.5*((3/8)*x*cos(deg(x))-(9/32)*sin(deg(x))-(1/32)*sin(3*deg(x))  )};
                \addlegendentry[scale=0.6]{$\gamma_{0,1}+\varepsilon\gamma_{1,1}$}
                %node [pos=0.5, below=200, scale=0.8] {$\gamma_{0,1}=\cos t$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).